# Kubernetes, access IP outside the cluster

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have a corporate network(10.22.*.*) which hosts a Kubernetes cluster(10.225.0.1). How can I access some VM in the same network but outside the cluster from within the pod in the cluster?

For example, I have a VM with IP 10.22.0.1:30000, which I need to access from a Pod in Kubernetes cluster. I tried to create a Service like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vm-ip
spec:
  selector:
    app: vm-ip
  ports:
    - name: vm
      protocol: TCP
      port: 30000
      targetPort: 30000
  externalIPs:
    - 10.22.0.1
```

But when I do "curl http://vm-ip:30000" from a Pod(kubectl exec -it), it returns "connection refused" error. But it works with "google.com". What are the ways of accessing the external IPs?

Comment: `externalIPs` allows you to route traffic _into_ the cluster using an IP that Kubernetes does not control. Are you confusing it with `ExternalName`? Also, if the two internal networks are connected somehow, and your router has a route to that network, it should work without the need of an extra Service.

Comment: Have you tested if the VM is accessible from the pod running in your cluster or the Kubernetes worker nodes? The external routing is typically achieved by IP masquerading, which is done by the kube-proxy. Once you've established that the VM is indeed reachable, you can then set up an ExternalName service to have a friendlier name within the cluster.

Comment: If I just curl the IP of the VM it returns "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.22.0.1 port 30000: Connection timed out". I guess it's because Kubernetes tries to find the IP within its own network. Or maybe it's because the cluster is at AWS, and there should be some rules with routes to another subnets configured. ExternalName doesn't work with IPs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an [endpoint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/#endpoints-v1-core) for that.

Let's go through an example:

In this example, I have a http server on my network with IP `10.128.15.209` and I want it to be accessible from my pods inside my Kubernetes Cluster.

First thing is to create an endpoint. This is going to let me create a service pointing to this endpoint that will redirect the traffic to my external http server.

My endpoint manifest is looking like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: http-server
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.128.15.209
    ports:
      - port: 80
```

```
$ kubectl apply -f http-server-endpoint.yaml
endpoints/http-server configured
```

Let's create our service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: http-server
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

```
$ kubectl apply -f http-server-service.yaml
service/http-server created
```

Checking if our service exists and save it's clusterIP for letter usage:

```
user@minikube-server:~$$ kubectl get service
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
http-server   ClusterIP   10.96.228.220   <none>        80/TCP    30m
kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   10d
```

Now it's time to verify if we can access our service from a pod:

```
$ kubectl run ubuntu -it --rm=true --restart=Never --image=ubuntu bash
```

This command will create and open a bash session inside a ubuntu pod.

In my case I'll install curl to be able to check if I can access my http server. You may need install mysql:

```
root@ubuntu:/# apt update; apt install -y curl
```

Checking connectivity with my service using clusterIP:

```
root@ubuntu:/# curl 10.128.15.209:80
Hello World!
```

And finally using the service name (DNS):

```
root@ubuntu:/# curl http-server
Hello World!
```

So, in your specific case you have to create this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: vm-server
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.22.0.1
    ports:
      - port: 30000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vm-server
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 30000
      targetPort: 30000
```

Comment: Thanx, but I'm getting "connection timed out". I guess it's related to the network settings. Thanks.

Comment: It's something in the network for sure. Your cluster is Bare Metal? You can access this service from your Kubernetes Master node?

Comment: It's at AWS, and managed by cloud team. I thought that if I can ping the luster from the VM, then it should work in the reverse direction. But I guess the VPC should have routing to the subnet with VM.